# Deploy dacpac files through Powershell in Azure SQL DataWarehouse database

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, dacpac, azure-synapse

While deploying the dacpac file from powershell in Azure SQL DW database I am getting following error:
Exception calling "Deploy" with "3" argument(S): "An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue."

Is there any way to deploy dacpac file in Azure SQL DW Database using Powershell?

Comment: How do you deploy your dacpac file in PowerShell? Specifically what cmdlet are you using

Comment: We explicitly load the .net libraries (installed by SSDT) and then use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage` object in powershell to deploy the dacpac's

Answer (score 1):

SQL DW does not yet support database projects.  This feature is planned.  You can vote for this feature here, https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13313247-database-project-from-visual-studio-to-support-azu, which will also give you updates to the progress of this feature.